# Heat style auto-scaling between openstack and aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, openstack, autoscaling, openstack-heat

I would like to balance my heat auto-scaling between my openstack infrastructure and my aws cloud. Basically policy could be something like.. first 4 auto-scaling instances would be staged in my openstack system but next(or any subsequent) instance would be in my aws cloud. There is no security concerns straight way as this is a POC.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should need an External Load Balancer Or your Infastructure's Load Balancer with an AWS Elastic Load Balancer.

The AWS Load Balancer Will Distribute the load on the AWS Infastructure and An Another LB will Load Balance the Openstack Infastructure. After that you will need another Load Balancer to load Balance Between the too Load Balancers.

I think this Image Will describe what I am Saying:

[image]

Also the LB can be custom made (in Node.js or another Instance) in order to redirect the traffic between the 2 LB's So for each connection to Lb set a "price". The Lower "price" wins and on each n connections recalculate the price for each connection between Lb's.

The price policy also can be set by you. Eg. the price can be the number of connections redirected or a value that is getting Increased every 100 connections. I mean Having 2 way Lb allows you to manually redirect the traffic in order to tell where the application will autoscale.

In the end on how to Autoscale the Openstack Infastructure I think the Openstack should decide that. https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat/AutoScaling